# How to handle "ref" of MUI component props in our components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui

I currently have the following custom component:

```
// ...
import { PaperProps, styled } from '@mui/material';

type ComponentProps = PaperProps & {
  a: string,
  b: string
};

export const MyPaper = styled(Paper)(/* ... */);

const Component: FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const { a, b, ...other } = props;
  // ...
  return <MyPaper {...other}>...</MyPaper>
};
```

It has its own props, but I also want it to receive PaperProps from Mui. However, those props contain a "ref" prop, and I'm not sure if I should pass it down directly:

```
// ...

type ComponentProps = PaperProps & {
  a: string,
  b: string
};

const Component: FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const { a, b, ...other } = props;
  // ...
  return <MyPaper {...other}>...</MyPaper>
};
```

or use forwardRef and Omit the "ref" prop from PaperProps:

```
// ...

type ComponentProps = Omit<PaperProps, 'ref'> & {
  a: string,
  b: string
};

const Component = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ComponentProps>((props, ref) => {
  const { a, b, ...other } = props;
  // ...
  return <MyPaper ref={ref} {...other}>...</MyPaper>
});
```

What's the correct way of doing this? And do I need to explicitly Omit the "ref" props in my ComponentProps type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of the expected behavior :

- If you want `ref` to target the mui `Paper` component then you should use `forwardRef`

```
type ComponentProps = PaperProps & {
  a: string,
  b: string
};

const Component = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ComponentProps>((props, ref) => {
   ...
   return <MyPaper ref={ref} {...other}>...</MyPaper>
});

<Component ref={myRef} /> 
// myRef will target the Paper component
```

You don't need to use `Omit<PaperProps, 'ref`> because `forwardRef` already do it for you as we can see in its type definition by using `PropsWithoutRef` :

`function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;`

- If you want `ref` to target your component `Component` (which I think is not what you want), then you should not use `forwardRef`.

```
const Component = (props) => {
   console.log(props); 
   // props do not contain the ref property
   // so it won't be forwarded to MyPaper
   ...
   return <MyPaper {...other}>...</MyPaper>
};

<Component ref={myRef} /> 
// myRef will target Component (which is totally useless)
```

Comment: In your second example (without forwardRef), isn't the ref prop still there (coming from the PaperProps type)? Don't I need to Omit it as well in my props type definition?

Comment: As I said, the second example is useless, what would be the goal of getting the ref of a functional component ? If you want to use the ref you should follow the first example and use `forwardRef`. Using `Omit` is totally useless because forwardRef already do it for you (see [forwardRef](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L823C5-L823C142) type definition) it already uses `PropsWithoutRef<P>`